# An application of the Triangle Inequality

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds, triangle-inequality

I was wondering if what I did is right and is considered to be a valid approach when solving similar questions?

> Here is the question

[image]

> Here is what I did

I noticed that it is a question involving the triangle inequality, so I proceeded as follows:
$$|\frac{x^3+x^2-1}{x-6}| \leq |\frac{x^3}{x-6}| + |\frac{x^2}{x-6}| + |\frac{-1}{x-6}|$$ 
$$\leq |\frac{2^3}{2-6}| + |\frac{2^2}{2-6}| + |\frac{-1}{2-6}|$$
$$=3.25$$

Also, if the expression was $|\frac{1}{x^3+x^2-1}|$ instead of $|\frac{x^3+x^2-1}{x-6}|$, would we need to follow the same procedure but instead of plugging in $x = 2$, we would plug in $x = 1 $ since $\frac{1}{2}<\frac{1}{x}<1$?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant "$\leq$", not "$=$". I corrected it.

Comment: Isn't it justified by the triangle inequality because it's in the form of $|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$?

Comment: @SL_MathGuy for $1\le x\le 2$, that inequality is correct, because $x^3\le 2^3$, and also $|x-6|\ge |2-6|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your steps are correct. But you can also notice that the numerator is monotonically increasing for $1\le x \le 2$, and the absolute value of the denominator is monotonically decreasing for $1\le x \le 2$, so

$$\left|\frac{x^3+x^2-1}{x-6}\right|\le\frac{|2^3+2^2-1|}{|2-6|}=\frac{11}{4}.$$

If you have $\left|\frac{1}{x^3+x^2-1}\right|$, you can use again the fact that $x^3+x^2-1$ is monotonically increasing for $1\le x\le 2$. This means that
$$1\le x^3+x^2-1\le 11$$
and the same is true for $|x^3+x^2-1|$. Taking inverses reverses the inequalities, so
$$1\ge \frac{1}{|x^3+x^2-1|}\ge \frac{1}{11}.$$

Your upper bound is $1$ in this case.

Comment: Thanks! Could you just please explain what you mean by monotonically increasing and decreasing?

Comment: @Abwatts "Monotonically increasing" means that, if you increase $x$, the numerator also increases. This is easy to verify, because the numerator has only positive terms that depend on $x$, and $x$ is also positive.

Comment: I see, thank you! I am also a bit unclear of what would be the case if the expression was instead $|\frac{1}{x^3+x^2-1}|$?

Comment: @Abwatts see updated answer.